# Copy **array1 Contents to **array2 in C

Tags: c, shell, multidimensional-array

I am doing a shell program in C. I am working on the simulation of the "!!" command which fetch the previous command and executes it. I am trying to copy *currentargv[] contents to *prevargv[] in order to save the command just given for future use. I was trying to use strcpy but not sure if it works with multidimensional arrays. This is one part of my code:

```
/*We are going to save in 'buffer' the words (separated by the null char)
*given by user which are going to be processed by parse(). 'buffer' is going
* to be reused on the next prompt and previous contents are going to be 
* overwritten, that is why i want to copy its contents to another place.
*/
char buffer[STORAGE];

/*They only point to contents in buffer*/
char *outputfile;
char *inputfile;
char *errfile;

/*cmd.newargv is going to store the program name in cmd.newargv[0];
* the other blocks of memory are going to store the arguments to the 
*given to the program i.e 'echo hello world'. All this pointers are 
*fetched from buffer
*/
struct Command{
  int indx;
  char **newargv;
}cmd;

struct Save {
  int indx;
  char *newargv[STORAGE];
  char outfile[STORAGE];
  char infile[STORAGE];
  char errfile[STORAGE];
}prevCmd;
//main()
//prompt for user for input 
//parse input
//call saveCommand "explicitly used for the '!!' command"
//execute command (fork(), execvp(), etc.)

void saveCommand {
  strcpy(prevCmd.inputfile, inputfile);
  strcpy(prevCmd.outputfile, outputfile);
  strcpy(prevCmd.errfile, errfile);
  //Here want to copy contents in cmd.newargv to prevCmd.newargv.
}
```

I ommit much of my code on saveCommand for simplicity. Also I am not sure if this is the best way to implement the "!!" command functionality. If you know another way to implement this i will really like to know it. Thanks

Comment: There is no multidimensional array in the snippet shown. A pointer is not a array, nor is a _pointer to pointer to `char`_ one.

Comment: I just edited the title thanks.